# Handling optional Parameters in Python

Tags: python, django, rest

I'm trying to solve an issue related to my api and want to refactor my code to work backward, i mean if the front-end doesn't send me the data i want, the request should go through , and if the front-end does send, it would still work as usual.

So roughly my  create function works fine however , when the front end team sent data without what the server expects it does break with a 500 Internal Server Error, but i want to make it optional, even though the data expected is not  sent , i want to get a 200 Http response, here is where the code breaks because of the key error on the job_invoice.I've tried to use in my for loop the break to bypass it .. but still.

```
job_invoice_data = inv_data['job_invoice']
    job_invoice = JobInvoice.objects.create(job=job_instance,   **job_invoice_data)
    obj.job_invoice = job_invoice

    # Create an InvoiceLineItem for each element in invoice_line_item

    for invoice_line_item in inv_data['invoice_line_item']:
        invoice_line_item['job_invoice'] = job_invoice.id
        if invoice_line_item['job_invoice'] is None:
            break
        invoice_line_item_serializer = InvoiceLineItemSerializer(data=invoice_line_item)
        if invoice_line_item_serializer.is_valid():
            invoice_line_item_obj = invoice_line_item_serializer.save()
        else:
            logger.debug("Couldn't create invoice line item: {}".format(invoice_line_item))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Solution:** Use Try and Catch Blocks

```
try:
    #Parse all parameters here
except:
    pass
```

**More Complex:**

Check availability of the parameters and proceed only when its available but use the default value none.

For example in Flask you can do something like this:

```
@app.route("/func/<required_param>", defaults={"opt1": None, "opt2": None,"opt3": None})
```

Comment: Ali Jafri, simply works after something i was forgetting.

Comment: Awesome, keep it up.

Comment: :) Thanks I will.